# Can I output a custom taxonomy as a submenu in the site navigation menu?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, archives, navigation

I'm building a WP 3.2 site with a couple of custom post types and taxonomies. I'm calling one of these custom post types *programs*, and its associated taxonomy is called *topics*.

I'd like to add an item called "Topics" in the site's horizontal navigation, with a dropdown submenu that lists all categories in the *topics* taxonomy. Each submenu item would then link to its respective category archive page.

Is this possible? I assumed this would be pretty easy in WordPress, but I've been searching around for a while to no avail.

**EDIT:** [This blog post and plugin](http://www.alistercameron.com/2009/12/13/wordpress-plugin-add-categories-menu/) come close, but it seems to only apply to blog categories (that is, I don't see how to adapt it for a custom taxonomy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enabled by default if your using `wp_nav_menu` ( the drag & drop menu's in admin) and have also set `show_in_nav_menus` to true for your `register_taxonomy`.

To enable them to show go to  Admin-->Appearance-->Menus

Click "Screen Options" in the top right and you should see it listed there.

ps. The post you linked is obsolete.